# No sound in Xubuntu after starting from command line

Tags: command-line, sound, xubuntu

When I first installed Xubuntu, everything was working fine. Then I encountered a problem where it would start up in the command line with no GUI, but I fixed that by typing startx. The problem, though, is that whenever I start it up from the command line, the sound is muted. I am using version 12.04 on a Dell Dimension 3000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startx` is not the preferred way to start a session in Ubuntu.

Use `sudo start lightdm` instead and that should start your session the right way (and in doing so, hopefully kick pulseaudio into gear at the same time).

I'm sure there's an `xinit` way of doing this too, but honestly, just going with the standard `lightdm` route is probably the sanest.